# Split date range into weeks and sum columns based on the week

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm calling in data from a DB where each record is associated with a (column) 'start_time', 'no_shows and 'cancelled'. Successful attendance is based on whether 'no_shows' && 'cancelled' == 0.

I want to go through the results of this SELECT and count the number of no shows, cancellations and attended on a WEEKLY basis (based on the start_time). How can I achieve this?

The user will provide a date range and the DB will select the records based on that date range. Now this date range will then have to be split by weeks and then get the count. I'm totally stuck on the counting by weeks part. This is what I have so far:

```
    // Multidimensional Array with [boolean][week #]
  $no_shows_weekly = [
    'no_show' => [],
    'week' => []
  ];
  $cancelled_weekly = [
    'cancelled' => [],
    'week' => []
  ];
  $attended_weekly = [
    'attended' => [],
    'week' => []
  ];

  foreach($result as $r) {
    $start_time = new DateTime($r['start_time']);
    if($r['is_no_show'] == 0 && $r['is_cancelled'] == 0) {
        array_push($attended_weekly['attended'], 1);
        array_push($attended_weekly['week'], date_format($start_time, "W"));
    }
    else {
      array_push($attended_weekly['attended'], 0);
      array_push($attended_weekly['week'], date_format($start_time, "W"));
    }
    array_push($no_shows_weekly['no_show'], $r['is_no_show']);
    array_push($no_shows_weekly['week'], date_format($start_time, "W"));
    array_push($cancelled_weekly['cancelled'], $r['is_cancelled']);
    array_push($cancelled_weekly['week'], date_format($start_time, "W"));
  }
  echo json_encode(array(
       'success'=> 1,
       'msg'=>
         array(
           'No Shows' => $no_shows_weekly,
           'Cancellations' => $cancelled_weekly,
           'Attendend' => $attended_weekly
         )
    ));
```

I wasn't able to do any counting in this, rather I just pulled the data and separated into arrays with the corresponding week.

I want to pull data into something like this:

```
Week 50: {No_Shows: 10, Cancelled: 5, Attended: 25} 
Week 52: {No_Shows: 10, Cancelled: 5, Attended: 25}
```

General DB Structure:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+
| start_time |  no_shows | cancelled | 
+------------+-----------+-----------+
| 2019-12-20 |     1     |     0     |   
| 2019-12-21 |     0     |     0     |  
| 2019-12-22 |     0     |     1     |
```

I tried to do this in MySQL as well:

```
    SELECT
    WEEKOFYEAR('start_time') AS weekno,
    SUM('is_no_show' = 1) AS no_shows,
    SUM('is_cancelled' = 1) AS cancelled
FROM
    myTable
WHERE
    (
        `start_time` > '2019-12-01' AND `start_time` < '2019-12-07'
    ) AND category LIKE 'Continued Probation'
GROUP BY
    weekno
```

However, this statement is returning Null for me. Any suggestions is appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Single quotes are for strings (and date literals), not field identifiers; for those you use `\``. You used the correct ones in your WHERE conditions, but not in your SELECT expressions. _Also, `LIKE` without wildcards is equivalent to `=`._

Comment: @Uueerdo wow this solved everything lol. To get the total attended though is it fine to get the total records and then subtract (no_shows + cancelled)?

Comment: It's hard to tell with the limited data you've provided, but if start_time is some sort of , identifier for what is being attended, and is repeated for each... reservation(?), and `no_shows` and `cancelled` are basically flags for each possible attendee, then record count - sum of no shows and cancelled sounds right.